# Play framework Form with HashMap

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do I use `HashMap` with play Scala template. My controller is in Java.

Following is my model:

```
public class DataModel extends Model {
    public Map<String, String> dataMap;
    public Map<String, String> getDataMap() {
        return dataMap();
    }
}
```

Following is the template:

```
@(purchaseOrder: String, computerForm: Form[DataModel])
    ....
@for((key, value) <- computerForm("dataMap")) {
    @inputText(value, '_label -> key)
}
```

But I getting following error:

```
value filter is not a member of play.data.Form.Field
editForm.scala.html at line 15.

<fieldset>
    **@for((key, value) <- computerForm("dataMap"))** { 
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Pass the object without wrapping in Form and check if this solves your problem. This question is enigmatic and without better sample it will be hard to guess what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an object that is not a `Form` to a template, declare the object's type directly in the template. There is no need to wrap it in a `Form`.

For instance:

```
@(purchaseOrder: String, computerForm: DataModel)
```

See [the template engine documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplates) for more information.